# addEventListener not triggering function on click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The solution to this problem is probably pretty simple, but I need some help.

```
var x;
for(x in document.getElementsByTagName("img"))
    x.addEventListener('click',openPage, false);

function openPage() {
    alert("clicked");
}
```

I'm not getting an alert when I click on an `<img src="something" />` tag. Anyone know why? Also, is my loop necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code produces an error - in a for..in statement, 'x' is the key of your object (in this case, your `document.getElementsByTagName` call). What you want is:

```
var x,
    imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for(x in imgs) {
    if (imgs[x] instanceof Element) {
        imgs[x].addEventListener('click',openPage, false);
    }
}

function openPage() {
    alert("clicked");
}
```

Might I suggest using a Javascript framework (like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)), which can help simplify your code as such:

```
$('img').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
       alert('Clicked!');
       // Now that we're in the callback context, $(this) will be the current
       // target - the specific image that was clicked.
       // i.e. $(this).fadeOut() would slowly fade out the clicked image.
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, small typo in the word `function`. I've corrected it and added a little more validation in the loop while I was at it. :)

Comment: I should have seen that. I'm a bit embarrassed about that. The reason why I said it didn't work was different, however. I'm making a chrome extension and while the code works in the jsfiddle.net, it doesn't work in my chrome extension.

Comment: Oh, then I go back to my second suggestion, which was to use jQuery. You can always link to the Google-hosted jQuery library which will usually be cached. It will greatly simplify your code and (once you get comfortable with it) speed up your development. Unfortunately, my experience with Chrome extensions is quite limited, so I wouldn't be of much help beyond that.